# Problems related to create a .bat file using Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am using the following code to create a .bat file based on the contents of a array of dimensions 5 x 3 (five rows, 3 columns). Each line of the batch file must contain elements stored on each row of the array, this is line 1 of the batch file must be: array(1,1) array(1,2) array(1,3) with each element of the array separated by an space and enclosing the elements in double quotes (").

The key here (I believe) is that the number of characters in each element of the array is high (they are long paths to network files)

Following the code I am using:

```
Sub Global_batch_creation()

Workbooks.Add
For i = 1 To numCases
    Cells(i, 1) = Chr(34) & globalBatch(i, 1) & Chr(34) & Space(1)
    Cells(i, 2) = Chr(34) & globalBatch(i, 2) & Chr(34) & Space(1)
    Cells(i, 3) = Chr(34) & globalBatch(i, 3) & Chr(34)
Next i

Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit 'This is to make all content _
'visible, which I think is required when using the FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter below

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=batchFile & ".bat" _
, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

The resulting file is truncated at column 2, where the contents corresponding to column 3 appear in rows 6 to 10 of the .bat file.

How can I force all the contents of every row in the array to be placed in the same line of the .bat file?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Pegaso

Comment: what is the value of `numCases`?  where is numCases defined? where is the value of numCases set?

Comment: Why not just write to the file directly?

Comment: just to test your code ... replace `globalBatch(i, 1)` in your code by "abc12345" for all three. replace `numCases` with `4` ... then run again

Comment: numCases is an integer value 4 in this cases, it will dictate the number of rows in the .bat file. Thanks for ask!

Comment: Alternatively you can use [Scripting.FileSystemObject (FSO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx) to create and write the batch file line-by-line, or at once by having a String variable to concatenate all the cells content of those rows. You may have excessive `"` and spaces with the way you tackle it. With FSO, you can check the paths if valid, etc.

Comment: I thought about writing to the file directly, but I believe (correct me if I am wrong) that this will require to have a an empty .bat file stored somewhere to open, write to it and save it, the problem with that is that I want to distribute the code and don't want to point to files that maybe are stored in a location the user can't access.

Comment: @Pegaso your wrong...lol.  [CreateTextFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: The [OpenTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx) method lets you create one if not already exist. If the user who runs the macro without permission to the folder, I am sure Excel VBA can't do it either.

Comment: I ran jsotola suggestion and indeed every line in the .bat contains the "abc123" string, the .bat file contains 4 lines and not 8 as before, therefore I still suspect that the problem is the length of the rows

Comment: replace `globalBatch(i, 1)` with `String(2000, "x")` ... use `String(2000, "y")` and `String(2000, "z")` for the other two.   replace `numCases` with `1` and run ..... result ... undesirable and weird .... if you comment out the `autofit` line than the cause becomes clear

Comment: I will try Thomas & Patrick's suggestion and post back. Thanks!

Comment: change the file format to `FileFormat:=xlText`  ... that fixes it, but adds a quote mark issue

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Thomas & Patrick!

There is nothing better than using the right tool for the job!

```
Sub Global_batch_creation()

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(batchFile & ".bat", True)
    For i = 1 To numCases
        a.WriteLine (Chr(34) & globalBatch(i, 1) & Chr(34) & Space(1) _
                    & Chr(34) & globalBatch(i, 2) & Chr(34) & Space(1) _
                    & Chr(34) & globalBatch(i, 3) & Chr(34) & Space(1))

    Next i
    a.Close
End Sub
```

This is what happens when someone doesn't have the right education for the job, fortunately you guys are here for the rescue!

Comment: I write another function to do the quotes for more readability. `Function Q(sText As String) As String : Q = """" & sText & """" : End Function` Then you can do `a.WriteLine Join(Array(Q(globalBatch(i, 1)),Q(globalBatch(i, 2)),Q(globalBatch(i, 3)))," ")`